# How can I have Unity inspector treat a file extension as a different file extension?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For example I have .BGM files which I know are renamed .OGG
How can I make Unity aware of this, or add a way to play them within Unity.

I want to treat the files as another file type.

Comment: Rename them in Windows? Unity doesn't actually make a distinction by file name for the most part (the `AssetDatabase` class is the only thing I've ever found that needs the extension, is Editor side only, and deals directly with the file system).

Comment: Unity only distinguishs between e.g. AudioClip, Sprite, etc. If you go to the inspector youigjt be able to change how the file is imported

Comment: I was hoping I could do it without renaming.
I can load them at runtime just fine from the Streaming Assets had to specify the type.
musicPlayer.clip = www.GetAudioClip(false, false, AudioType.OGGVORBIS);

But that is not previewing them in the inspector.
So I made a custom inspector window with a button to play the BGM, although for some reason it won't load there it's like my button is greyed out.